# Normalize Retina image background in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, normalization

I have been working with the image of the retina, I have read many post and I have tried to replicate, I read an article where they use the following formula to normalize and that the bottom of the image does not affect the blood vessels, only that time to use it in OpenCV does not work in the same way, so I do not know how I can normalize so that the vessels are not affected by the bottom of the retina. Next I leave the code that I used,

```
 using namespace cv;
 using namespace std;


 int main(int argc, char** argv ){
    Mat green= cv::imread("green.png");
    Mat img= cv::imread("img.jpg");

    double minVal; 
    double maxVal; 


    minMaxLoc( green, &minVal, &maxVal);

    cout << "min val : " << minVal << endl;
    cout << "max val: " << maxVal << endl;

    double minVal2; 
    double maxVal2; 
    double media = 58;
    minMaxLoc( img, &minVal2, &maxVal2);

    cout << "min val : " << minVal2 << endl;
    cout << "max val: " << maxVal2 << endl;

    Mat eqIm(green.rows,green.cols,green.type());
    int nl = img.rows; // number of lines
    int nc = img.cols * img.channels();
    for (int j = 0; j<nl; j++) {// j is each row
        for (int ec = 0; ec < nc; ec++) {//ec is each col and channels
            eqIm.data[j*img.cols*img.channels() + ec] = 
            ((green.data[j*img.cols*img.channels() + ec] - (maxVal)) *(((maxVal2-minVal2/((minVal)-(maxVal)))+ (minVal2))));
      }
  }


 imwrite("eqIm.png", eqIm);



 waitKey(0);
 return 0;
}
```

I show the results also of the images, below you can see the original images:

- [image: retina original]
- [image: green image]

The result image:

[image: result image]

The formula used:

[image: Normalization equation]

Comment: I seperate the colorful region, then do the op on it, but the result is not that good either. https://i.stack.imgur.com/44EOq.png

Comment: how did you separate the region? the results are better than mine

Comment: My answer was down vote by others, so I deleted it, I will not answer this question.

Comment: but i think that this is interesting how do you separate... Could you tell me how do you do this process?

Comment: I said I would not answer this any more and I will do so. But someone said he was working on this. `I'm working on it. In the meantime, I'd consider converting this answer to a comment. It really doesn't answer the question. – rayryeng 2017-11-21 06:52` You may look forward to his answer.